I have question on Fluent DetailList control regarding the adding column
I am using the Fluent DetailList custom control in a Canvas application and want to add an external PCF component to this Fluent DetailList control as column. Should I integrate or create a column for external PCF custom control into the Fluent Detail List?
I have used the simple columns but need to add external PCF as column
